# VLC - crossfade fade in/out

Tags: vlc, music, media-buttons

Is it possible to add a fade out/in effect to VLC when it pauses/plays, and a crossfade effect when it changes track?

I found [this](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/crossfade-vlc-58730.html) as a some sort solution but not a great one. [This](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=122737) mentions [a github page](https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlc), which doesn't really mention what it does.

Using VLC 2.2.0 from `ppa:videolan/stable-daily` on 14.04, and 2.2.* on other machines. Could use different version if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, if [this thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=39707) is anything to go off of, cross-fade in VLC is not easily feasible as the core of the program does not support gapless music and any add-on enabling cross-fade would have to "edit" the core of the program. There is no add-on listed on the [official add-on repository](http://addons.videolan.org)  either.

Comment: Thats annoying. Oh well, I have translated various playlist into long videos (with crossfade), which also allows me to use them across varying systems and video players.